# Is excel data label with line chart C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I am trying to add data labels in excel **line charts** using C#.

But I have some questions in it.

- Is it really compatible to use data label in excel line charts?
- What if data is too much and it starts looking so hotchpotch?
- Can I add more then one data label at the same point in the series? Because I did it in C# but it is showing only last one.
- How to change data label shape? How to change data label size?

If anyone has solution or suggestion please suggest me. It will be highly appreciated.

Thanks